# How do I make an Infinite marquee with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to make an Infinite marquee that speeds up on scroll, https://altsdigital.com/ you can see the effect on this website, the text says "Not your usual SEO agency" and when you scroll it speeds up.

Here's what I've tried but it does not work. It does not loop properly without overlapping (keep your eye on the left side of the page, you'll notice the text briefly overlaps and then translates left to create a gap) and I am unsure on how to fix it:

Here's the code (TEXT ONLY VISIBLE ON "FULL PAGE" view):

```js
const lerp = (current, target, factor) => {
    let holder = current * (1 - factor) + target * factor;
    holder = parseFloat(holder).toFixed(3);
    return holder;
};

class LoopingText {
    constructor(DOMElements) {
        this.DOMElements = DOMElements;
        this.lerpingData = {
            counterOne: { current: 0, target: 0 },
            counterTwo: { current: 100, target: 100 },
        };
        this.interpolationFactor = 0.1;
        this.speed = 0.2;
        this.render();
        this.onScroll();
    }

    onScroll() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            this.lerpingData["counterOne"].target += this.speed * 5;
            this.lerpingData["counterTwo"].target += this.speed * 5;
        });
    }

    lerp() {
        for (const counter in this.lerpingData) {
            this.lerpingData[counter].current = lerp(
                this.lerpingData[counter].current,
                this.lerpingData[counter].target,
                this.interpolationFactor
            );
        }

        this.lerpingData["counterOne"].target += this.speed;
        this.lerpingData["counterTwo"].target += this.speed;

        if (this.lerpingData["counterOne"].target < 100) {
            this.DOMElements[0].style.transform = `translate(${this.lerpingData["counterOne"].current}%, 0%)`;
        } else {
            this.lerpingData["counterOne"].current = -100;
            this.lerpingData["counterOne"].target = -100;
        }

        if (this.lerpingData["counterTwo"].target < 100) {
            this.DOMElements[1].style.transform = `translate(${this.lerpingData["counterTwo"].current}%, 0%)`;
        } else {
            this.lerpingData["counterTwo"].current = -100;
            this.lerpingData["counterTwo"].target = -100;
        }
    }

    render() {
        this.lerp();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
    }
}

let textArray = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
new LoopingText(textArray);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

.hero-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.loop-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    /* padding-right: 24px; */
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    cursor: default;
}

.hover:hover {
    color: gray;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="hero-section">
        <div class="loop-container">
            <div class="item">Infinite Horizontal Looping Text</div>
            <div class="item">Infinite Horizontal Looping Text</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="hero-section">
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: looks sped up to me - can't read the text at all

Comment: @Bravo the problem is that the text is overlapping on the loop. and then briefly translating left.

Comment: the problem here looks like you can only see a fraction of the the top of the text - so, your described issue is not obvious

Comment: @Bravo I think it's a stack overflow bug, you have to click "full page" to see it completely. Basically "text" is overlapping on the word "infinite" very briefly on the left and then the word "text" translates left to make the gap. I don't know why,

Comment: oh, right, that's subtle but yes - perhaps make a note in the question that the issue is only visible on full page snippet :p

Comment: Your example does not change animation direction depending on scroll direction ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know, sorry let me remove that extra code. I was planning for it to do that later. But what causes the brief translation to the left and overlap of the text? I am unsure about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your items are overlapping because you're not allowing any **lerping diffing** when the items should switch positions.

The `current` value should **never** equal the `target` value. If the values match, than the current value needs to *catch up* the `target` — giving that erratic movement and wrong calculations, additionally aggravated for the two sibling elements which should be perfectly in sync to give that immediate snap-back, perceived as a fluid continuous motion.

### Solution

- Instead of animating two (or more) children independently,
  **animate only the parent `.loop-container`**.
- The container should be as **wide** as **one child element** exactly.
- "Push" one child element to the far left using `position: absolute; left: -100%`
- To allow the `target` value to be always **greater** than the `current` value:
  when the `target` value is greater than `100` — set `current` to the **negative difference** of the two values, and `target` to `0`

<sub>Demo time:</sub>

```js
const lerp = (current, target, factor) => current * (1 - factor) + target * factor;

class LoopingText {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.lerp = {current: 0, target: 0};
    this.interpolationFactor = 0.1;
    this.speed = 0.2;
    this.direction = -1; // -1 (to-left), 1 (to-right) 
    
    // Init
    this.el.style.cssText = `position: relative; display: inline-flex; white-space: nowrap;`;
    this.el.children[1].style.cssText = `position: absolute; left: ${100 * -this.direction}%;`;
    this.events();
    this.render();
  }

  events() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => this.lerp.target += this.speed * 5);
  }

  animate() {
    this.lerp.target += this.speed;
    this.lerp.current = lerp(this.lerp.current, this.lerp.target, this.interpolationFactor);
    
    if (this.lerp.target > 100) {
      this.lerp.current -= this.lerp.target;
      this.lerp.target = 0;
    }

    const x = this.lerp.current * this.direction;
    this.el.style.transform = `translateX(${x}%)`;
  }

  render() {
    this.animate();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".loop-container").forEach(el => new LoopingText(el));
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body { min-height: 400vh;  /* force some scrollbars */ }

.hero-section {
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 900 9vw/1 sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero-section">
  <div class="loop-container">
    <div class="item">Infinite Horizontal Looping Text&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="item">Infinite Horizontal Looping Text&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

PS:

When animating, (unless you want an element static / immovable) you should never put an elements transformations inside an if/else logic. The element should always receive the updated transformations. Put inside the conditional logic only the values that you actually want to modify (as I did in the example above).

Comment: Bought you a coffee :) you deserve it. i spend 15 hours on this and couldn't figure it out lol

Comment: Thank you @awawawaw much appreciated ☕ !!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Great Answer

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, thank you

Comment: This is better than all the others I've seen on the net that glitch after one cycle.

Comment: Thank you! @thdoan edited now to add a `direction` property for the scroll... direction :)